# When I add a Toon shader outline to mesh, the mesh color change

Tags: shaders

[image]

I use solidify to add an outline, however, when I enlarge the thickness, the outline layer will cover the toon shader layer.

I followed the Lightning Boy Studio tutorial on youtube.
[image]
When he changes the outline, the mesh color doesn't change.

Comment: I can only guess that this method simply has its limitations and you cannot use it for any arbitrary thickness... is there any mentionig of that in the tutorial? I don't know which one you are referring to, there are many Lightning Boy Studio tutorials on toon shaders.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be unique and identifying and summarize what the issue is, so that visitors can at a glance understand broadly what your post is about from the question list. Please use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors will see, and weights on their decision to open your question or not, so the number of answers you might get depends heavily on it.